# Delete text from Notepad++ REGEX

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to delete all texts but keep texts that are 32 in length and contain a-fA-F0-9

How can I do it?

I'm using notepad++ btw

Comment: What do you mean by "texts"?

Comment: Please show a before and after example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for:

```
^(?![a-FA-F0-9]{32}$).*
```

Replace with (leave blank). Leave `.` matches new line **unchecked**.

Test input:

```
0234020ab023ba023ab0a283924892a5
klsjfs
3298472847298374982374928749827394873942
023abecedf86596783495a28392482a5
0234020ab023ba023ab0a283924892g5
```

The regex basically search for all **lines** that doesn't contain `^[a-FA-F0-9]{32}$`, which is what you want to keep.

The `(?!...)` is zero-width negative look-ahead, which looks ahead in the text and allow the match to continue if the text ahead doesn't match the pattern inside. It doesn't consume text (zero-width), which means the match continue from where it were before it enter `(?!...)`.